# Infer Parameter Type based on Usage

Tags: c#, reflection

I have wired problem, I know Inference requires the use of an open generic.

Is ther a way to call  AssertDictionary(o2, o1);   by Reflection.
What I want is, use Type of o1 say t1 and o2 say t2 as AssertDictionary(o1, o2);

does this make sense?

```
 public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Person> actual = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
        actual.Add(10, new Person{Address="Abc", Name = "Dipak"});

        Dictionary<int, Person> expected = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
        expected.Add(10, new Person { Address = "Abc", Name = "Dipak" });

        object o1 = actual;
        object o2 = expected;
        CallAssert(o1, o2);
    }

     private static CallAssert(object exp, object act)
     {
            AssertDictionary(exp, act);// I'm doing it at runtime by reflection and actual & expected are of type System.Object
     }


 private static void AssertDictionary<TKey, TVal>(Dictionary<TKey, TVal> expected, Dictionary<TKey, TVal> actual)
    {
        if (expected != null && actual != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> valuePair in expected)
            .....
            .....
        }
     }
```

Can I create dynamic method at runtime and Call AssertDictionary  from there with Generic types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you have to use reflection, you can do it like this (assuming `Program` is the type containing `AssertDictionary()`):

```
// get the method
var openMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(
    "AssertDictionary", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

// get type arguments of the dictionary
var dictTypeArgs = o1.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

// set the type parameters of the method
var closedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dictTypeArgs);

// invoke the method
closedMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { o1, o2 });
```

Another option is to use `dynamic` and infer the type parameters at runtime automatically:

```
AssertDictionary((dynamic)o1, (dynamic)o2);
```

I think there is no need to create any dynamic methods here.

Comment: I think you have provided me guidance, Let me put it in my Code. Look I'm near to achieve this.

Comment: `var openMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("AssertDictionary", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
            
// get type arguments of the dictionary
var dictTypeArgs = o1.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

// set the type parameters of the method
var closedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dictTypeArgs);

// invoke the method
closedMethod.Invoke(this, new [] { o1, o2 });`

This Code worked for me.  thanks svick

Answer (score 0):

if you are planing on using reflection you are assuming you already know the type unles you are plaing to iterate through the memebrs.

try this:

```
        Dictionary<int, Person> actual = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
        actual.Add(10, new Person { Address = "Abc", Name = "Dipak" });

        Dictionary<int, Person> expected = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
        expected.Add(10, new Person { Address = "Abc", Name = "Dipak" });

        object o1 = actual;
        object o2 = expected;

        AssertDictionary((Dictionary<int, Person>)o2, (Dictionary<int, Person>)o1);
```

Or you can tell the compiler that you are shure what you are doing by using the dynamic keyword.

```
AssertDictionary((dynamic)o1, (dynamic)o2);
```

and to avoid having to cast each type to type dynamic then you should modify the method instead **I do not recoment using this technique though**

```
    private static void AssertDictionary(dynamic expected, dynamic actual)
    {
        // you will be able to call methods as:
        actual.Add(1, new Person()); // intelisence will not help you you have to be carefull with the dynamic type
        // I dont recoment using it if there is a work around
    }
```

### svik code looks much better. I will use his code if I where you...